# How to add data to an MUI table column-wise instead of row-wise?

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

Good day! [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hrbsnq?file=src%2FApp.js) is the sandbox react code that I'm using for a project involving MUI tables:

I have been racking my brain over this, but can't seem to get a solution. How can I add to this table column-wise instead of by row?

In line 57-67, the rows are created first and then they are populated row-wise, left-to-right by data.

The data given looks like this:

```
const data = [
   {name: "sample_name",
    calories: "19",
    fat: "90",
    carbs: 70,
    protein: 90},

{name: "sample_name",
    calories: "19",
    fat: "90",
    carbs: 70,
    protein: 90},
]
```

What the lines I mentioned do is it takes 1 of the objects in the data and appends them row-wise

I work with a data that looks like this:

```
const name = ["richard","nixon"]
const calories = [9, 9, 0, 9, 0, 5, 8]
const fat = [10, 9 , 9]
const carbs = [11, 3, 4,5 ]
const protein = [1, 1]
```

I just want to be able to insert name data into the name column... and so on... this should also hopefully make it easier for me to dynamically insert more data for each column using TextField+button action

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like this is a data issue, not Material UI. You need to provide row and column data to a table, regardless of what library you use, that's just how tables are build. So if you are getting back data by columns, you need a reducer or a method to convert them into rows. Here is a super quick and dirty example:

```js
const rawData = {
  name: ["Ice cream", "Sno cone"],
  calories: [32, 45]
};
let columns = Object.keys(rawData);
let rows = rawData.name.map((name, i) => {
  return { name, calories: rawData.calories[i] };
});
/*
rows = ["name", "calories"]
columns = [
  { name: "Ice cream", calories: 32 },
  { name: "Sno cone", calories: 45 },
];
*/
```

Obviously, this is a quick example and not very extensible, but should lead you in a good direction. Perhaps a reducer which could build out row data more elegantly. However, this will allow you to build out the table as intended:

```html
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <Table>
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {columns.map((i) => (
          <TableCell>{i}</TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.name}>
          <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.calories}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Comment: HI! I have a bit of a problem. The row's length only goes as far as the length of the name data, which in turn means the number of rows in the table is as only as many as there are data in name. If I am inserting data into calories and the amount of elements in calories, exceeds names, the table doesn't expand anymore.